# Trouble initializing object from custom class

Tags: c++

Sorry for my lack of experience in C++, I'm having issues understanding exactly what's happening in my code and why I can't initialize an object.

I'm using a class I found on github which contains the following relevant code (I removed code that I'm fairly certain isn't relevant).:

**Bee.h:**

```
class Bee {
public:
    Bee(HardwareSerial *serial, uint32_t baud);
private:
    // Prevent heap allocation
    void * operator new   (size_t);
    void * operator new[] (size_t);
};
```

**Bee.cpp**

```
#include "Bee.h"

Bee::Bee(HardwareSerial *serial, uint32_t baud) {
    // set some variables
}
```

So the example on github is for an Arduino and they use the line `Bee XBee(&Serial1, 9600);` to initialize the object named XBee in the .ino file above the setup() and loop() functions.

I'm building a class that requires a bee object. So I tried this:

**ADXBee.h**

```
#ifndef _ADXBee_h
#define _ADXBee_h

#include "Bee.h"

class ADXBee {
public:
    ADXBee();
private:
    Bee _bee;
};
```

**ADXBee.cpp**

```
#include "ADXBee.h"

ADXBee::ADXBee(){
    // Initialize serial
    Serial1.begin(9600);

    // Initialize Bee
    Bee _bee(&Serial1, 9600);
}
```

I've tried a number of different ways to initialize this and I unfortunately just don't have the background to ask this question in a way where I can google it. When I try to run this code I get this error:

```
ADXBee.h:66:30: warning: non-static data member initializers only available   with -std=c++1
1 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
ADXBee.cpp:In constructor 'ADXBee::ADXBee()'
ADXBee.cpp:16:16: error: no matching function for call to 'Bee::Bee()'
 ADXBee*:ADXBee(){
ADXBee.cpp:candidates are
Bee.h:Bee(SoftwareSerial*, uint32_t)
Bee.h:candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
Bee.h:Bee(HardwareSerial*, uint32_t)
Bee.h:candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
Bee.h:Bee(const Bee&)
Bee.h:candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Error compiling
```

Comment: I recognize that's true and I'm reading concurrent while trying to be productive :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Initialize Bee
Bee _bee(&Serial1, 9600);
```

That does not initialize the member of the same name. It just creates a function local object. You need to initialize it using the initializer list before the body of the function begins.

```
ADXBee::ADXBee() : _bee(<something>, 9600) { ... }
```

I am not sure what `<something>` needs to be since it's not clear from your post what would be a good value for `HardwareSerial *serial`.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I'll go do some reading to try to better understand what's going on here.